# Проблемы совместимости при отладке

Tags: отладка, c++

Осваиваю С++. Списала программу из задачника. При запуске отладки на строку `#iostream` etc получила комментарий "нет такой команды препроцессора".

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста, но вот сами посудите, как вам помочь? Вот я напишу - я написал какой-то код и у меня там что-то неработает, помогите мне :) Напишите пример кода, чтобы вам могли помочь...

Answer (score 3):

Наверное, вы хотели написать

```
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: Вы знаете, я очень грамотная. Я списала всё до последнего знака препинания. Это вопрос я задавала напамять, пока интернет работал (у нас перебои). В процессе печатания мне несколько раз выпадал плакат про устаревшую версию языка. Хотя задачник, из которого я писала, издания "Питер" 2010 года. Может ли этот казус быть связанным с тем, что сын (фанат последних версий) скачал самый свежий вариант visual Studio? и следует ли мне искать старую версию программы или новую версию самого языка?

Comment: Тогда было бы неплохо

 1. дать текст программы, хотя бы той части, которая вызывает сомнения;
 2. дать сообщения компилятора об ошибках;
 3. указать версию среды, компилятора и т.д. 

Иначе разговор ни о чем.

Comment: @Nathalie, а вот и неправда: в каких это учебниках пишут _#iostream_ такие вещи? Говорите название, мы пожалуемся в редакцию. Как-так то, очень грамотные девочки стараются, переписывают все до последнего знака _препинания_, и ради чего, спрашивается? Сие деяние не должно остаться безнаказанным.